# Обособление сравнительного оборота (разное решение в одном предложении)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

Правильная  пунктуация, это возможно?  А как такое объяснить?

*Настоящий мужчина сражается **как тигр**, но с близкими нежен и добр, **как ребенок.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правила приводить не буду (вы их прекрасно знаете), тем более что они здесь, как мне видится, применимы на все сто. Попробуем исходить из интонационного принципа. Логические ударения и паузы могут быть расставлены по-разному. Мой вариант такой (одна косая черта – чуть заметная пауза, две черты – более выраженная, и это всё субъективно и относительно):

*Настоящий мужчина / сражается как тИгр, // но с блИзкими // нежен и дОбр, / как ребёнок.*

***Как тигр*** выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия (*по-тигриному, "по-зверячьи"*) и не обособляется. ***Как ребёнок*** – чистое сравнение, не входящее в состав сказуемых ***нежен и добр***, перед которыми, кстати, даже тире можно влепить. Если последнюю паузу увеличить, то ***как ребёнок*** будет выглядеть ещё и как присоединение, будто бы мы хотели поставить точку, но решили добавить сравнение.

Не знаю, может ли такая несимметричная пунктуация являться правильной с точки зрения составителей тестов. А вот искушённый читатель, не раз сталкивающийся с проблематикой сравнительных оборотов, наверняка обратит на это внимание и задумается: "Нет ли здесь ошибки, на что сделал акцент автор, как бы я расставил здесь запятые?"

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, Александр!

1. Да, здесь все дело в **несимметричной интонации**. Мне не хотелось строить **два параллельных ряда:** (1) как тигр — как ребенок,  сражается — нежен и добр, но было желание выделить только один (такая композиция интереснее).
2. Я обратила внимание на подобный вариант в стихотворении **"Тамара" М.Лермонтова,** но сейчас не уверена, что там он вообще был. Тоже загадка!

*В той башне высокой и тесной*
*Царица Тамара жила:*
*Прекрасна, **как ангел небесный**,*
***Как демон**, коварна и зла.*

3. У Розенталя ([Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)):

Пункт 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом КАК не выделяется запятыми: 1) если на первый план выступает значение **обстоятельства образа действия** (обороты с КАК можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием): Как град посыпалась картечь (Л.) — ср.: градом посыпалась; **Как демон коварна и зла** (Л.) — ср.: демонически коварна...

4. Но сейчас во всех изданиях сравнение "как демон" **обособлено.** Так где ошибка, где авторский вариант? Теперь уж не узнаешь — у нас любят все одинаковое, оно и кажется правильным.
5. Хотела вам в подарок за ответ **найти запись песни** — и не нашла! Не нравится ничего: все голоса или грубые, или скрипучие, но главное — совсем невыразительные, без души.

Поэтому просто **большое спасибо за ответ!**

Comment: И вам тоже такое же спасибо!

Comment: Розенталь и Былинский позволяли себе менять примеры из классики. Не знаю, как можно себе такое позволить, но этот пример без запятой очень удачен (для этой темы). Ещё один пример модификации: *Я мчался на лихом коне, как ветер волен и один.* Здесь ещё и кусок изъяли.